# Duplicate record set is not automatically adding the duplicate record item

Tags: account, duplicate-management

I have created a duplicate rule for Account object to validate the name of the Account(meaning exact match as duplicate record), then I assigned that duplicate rule to a duplicate record set.

When I created an Account with an name that already exists, I don't see any duplicate record item added to the duplicate record set. But it allows to link or add any record(contact, opportunity, etc) manually to the duplicate record set.

Do I need to configure anything to activate Duplicate record management?

Answer (score 2):

Records can be added in the report by making Report Enabled in Duplicate Rules configuration. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Revisit your duplicate rule and the matching rule and make sure that they are active.

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm&language=en_US) Ideal steps are:

1. Create a duplicate rule
2. Specify Actions
3. Create a Matching Rule

Here is what must have happened. When you create a Matching Rule directly from the duplicate rule you would been redirected to the "New Matching Rule screen". You would have activated the matching rule, however your duplicate rule would be still inactive. You would have to revisit the duplicate rule and explicitly activate it. After this is done, you should see the error when you insert an account with exactly same name.

I verified this in my dev org. and works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see the error message while creating duplicate record but the records are not getting added to the ```DuplicateRecordSet``` as ```DuplicateRecordItem```

Comment: After receiving the error message, did you go ahead and clicked on the "Save(Ignore Alert)" button? The record would be added to the DuplicateRecordSet only after it is saved.

Comment: Yes, When I clicked on ```Save(Ignore Alert)``` the record got saved but there is no sign of the created record in ```DuplicateRecordSet```

Comment: is this in your Dev org or sandbox? Whats your profile (sys admin?)

Comment: Yes, my profile is sys admin

Answer (score 0):

To generate a Duplicate Record Set in Salesforce for existing records, ensure the following steps are correctly followed:

Activate

1. Duplicate Rule:

Confirm that your duplicate rule is set to "Active." You can do this in Salesforce Setup by navigating to "Data" > "Duplicate Rules" and ensuring that the rule is marked as active.

2. Check "Report" Checkbox:

In your duplicate rule, make sure that the "Report" checkbox is checked. This option is crucial for capturing duplicate records in a Duplicate Record Set.

3. Change Fields in Matching Rule:

To create a Duplicate Record Set, there must be a change in the fields specified in the matching rule. Duplicate detection relies on changes in these fields to identify duplicates. If no changes are made in these fields, a Duplicate Record Set won't be generated.

By following these steps, you should be able to activate Duplicate Record Management and successfully create Duplicate Record Sets in Salesforce.